# GoLand allows multiple main functions in the same package?

Tags: goland

**When using GoLand software
GoLand allows multiple main functions in the same package**

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple `main()` functions in the same package in GoLand.

However, you have to specify a file to run by the IDE and change *Run | Edit Configurations | Run kind* to File. It is identical to `go build main.go` command.